# How do I test sorting columns with Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, ide, calculated-columns

Up until now I have been a manual tester, but am the only one so I need to automate. I am completely new to automated testing and do not know any code whatsoever and most of it is over my head. With that said, I am trying using `Selenium IDE` to confirm the results of columns being sorted both ascending and descending. Through searching online I have seen that the best way is to use `concat` but am not sure how. When sorting descending I used `Firebug` and see that the application html for descending sorting says `onclick="sortResults(1, desc')`.  For ascending it says `onclick="sortResults(1, asc')`
So with my developers help I tried this after the clicking the link and waiting, to no avail:

**Command:** `assertElementPresent`

**Target:**

```
//a[contains(@onclick, concat("'", "sortResults(1, ", "'", "desc", "'", ")" ) ) ]
```

The result was error false.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Not sure what I did but I changed it and it worked! But the descending code also passes when ascending when it should fail. Any ideas? See the change I made below.

Command: assertElementPresent 
Target: //div[(concat("'", "sortResults(1, ", "'", "desc", "'", ")" ) ) ] 

and 

Command: assertElementPresent 
Target: //div[(concat("'", "sortResults(1, ", "'", "desc", "'", ")" ) ) ]

Comment: I got it and it verified the sort order of the columns. assertAttribute | link=Link | *sortResults(1,'desc')*               and for the reverse order                                            assertAttribute | link=Link | *sortResults(1,'asc')*